# Prove $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right| \le \dfrac{1}{a} \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 + \dfrac{a}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^2$

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

If $X,Y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a>0$ show that:
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right| \le \dfrac{1}{a} \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 + \dfrac{a}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^2 (*)$$

---

I started with Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and got:
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right| \le  {\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2}^\frac{1}{2}  \cdot{\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^2}^\frac{1}{2}(**)$$

So apparently we need to show that  $(**) < (*)$

and I'm stuck. Don't really know what to do with $a$'s.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right|  \le \sum_{i=1}^n\left| x_i y_i \right| $$

And for each $i$

$$|x_iy_i| \le \frac{1}{a}x_i^2 + \frac{a}{4}y_i^2$$

because $x + y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}$ when $x, y \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the other end, use AM-GM:
$$\dfrac{1}{a} \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 + \dfrac{a}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^2  \ge \left( \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^2 \right)^{1/2}$$
and finish off as you did with Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I did something similar, but then I asked myself if it's a good style to prove that something is right using something unknown.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what is it you consider unknown?  This just shows $(**) < (*)$ in your terminology.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your solution. Do you take LHS <= RHS and then after modifications get something that is right at the end?

Comment: Apply AM-GM on the two terms (sums) on the LHS, you get the RHS.  It is not an assumption, it is the proof.  Perhaps I should detail more.

Comment: No, it's fine. I got it. I just wanted to make sure that I don't use assumption and desired condition at the same time

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ we have
\begin{align*}
0&\leq\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{a}}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{a}y}{2}\right)^2\\
\text{i.e.}\qquad0&\leq\dfrac{1}{a}x^2\pm xy+\dfrac{a}{4}y^2 \\
|xy| &\leq\dfrac{1}{a}x^2+\dfrac{a}{4}y^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the inequality follows first from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and then by AM-GM inequality.